# The shell I am writing does not exit correctly after execvp() fails

Tags: c, linux, shell, execvp

I have an assignment to make a shell in C code, and I have a solution that works most of the time. My solution works if the program exists, and I can exit my shell with either <kbd>Control-D</kbd> or by typing exit. But when I try a command that I know doesn't exist, my shell will print an error message saying command not found but I will have to either type exit or press <kbd>Control-D</kbd> the same amount of times as a invalid command was entered i.e. if I type a wrong command 3 times, I then have to hit <kbd>Control-D</kbd> 3 times. I really don't know what is going on here. I checked all the variables and read is -1 when I press <kbd>Control-D</kbd> but the if statement seems to be skipped.

Here is the parts of my source code that I think the problem is in:

comp20200Shell.c

```
#include "comp20200Shell_header.h"
#include <signal.h>


/*
 * Name: ****
 * Student Number: ****
 * Email: ****
 *
 * This is the main function of my shell implementation.
 *
 */
int main(void)
{
    bool end_program = false;
    size_t length = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    char* current_directory = NULL;
    char* current_time = NULL;

    /* Sets up signal handler to catch SIGINT*/
    if(signal(SIGINT, sigintHandler) == SIG_ERR)
    {
        error("An error occured while setting a signal handler\n");
    }

    /* Infinitive loop, so after command or invalid comman will prompt again*/
    while(end_program != true)
    {
        char* input = NULL;

        /* Gets current working directory */
        current_directory = return_current_directory();

        /* Gets current date and time */
        current_time = return_time();

        /* Prints Prompt */
        printf("%s\x5b%s\x5d %s%s %s%s%s", MAGENTA_TEXT, current_time, GREEN_TEXT, current_directory, BLUE_TEXT, PROMPT, RESET_COLOUR);

        /* Frees the pointers returned by return_time() and return_current_directory() */
        free(current_time);
        free(current_directory);

        /* Reads one line from standard input */
        read = getline(&input, &length, stdin);

        /* Checks if ctrl d, i.e. end of file is found or exit is typed */
        if(strcmp(input, "exit\n") == 0 || read == -1)
        {
            if(read == -1)
            {
                putchar('\n');
            }
            /* Frees input */
            free(input);
            return(0);
        }

        /* Removes newline character that will be at the end */
        remove_trailing_newline(input);

        /* Passes input to process input, and the return value is passed in to process errors */
        process_errors(process_input(&input));

        /* Frees input */
        free(input);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

process_input.c

```
#include "comp20200Shell_header.h"
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

/*
 * Name: ****
 * Student Number: ****
 * Email: ****
 *
 * This function is used to process the command entered by the user
 *
 * return: the error value or 0 when everything whent ok
 * arguments: the command entered by the user
 *
 */
int process_input(char** input)
{
    bool redirect_stdout = false;
    bool redirect_stderr = false;

    pid_t child_pid;
    int child_status;
    char** argument = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    int count = 0;

    char* temp = strtok(*input, " ");
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        argument[count] = temp;
        count ++;
        argument = realloc(argument, (count+2) * sizeof(char *));
        temp = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    argument[count] = NULL;

    if(argument[0] == NULL)
    {
        return(0);
    }
    else if(strcmp(argument[0], "cd") == 0)
    {
        return(change_directory(argument[1]));
    }

    int index;
    for(index = 1; argument[index] != NULL; index++)
    {
        if(strcmp(argument[index], ">0") == 0)
        {
            if(argument[index + 1] == NULL)
            {
                return(EINVAL);
            }
            redirect_stdout = true;
            break;
        }
        else if(strcmp(argument[index], ">2") == 0)
        {
            if(argument[index + 1] == NULL)
            {
                return(EINVAL);
            }
            redirect_stderr = true;
            break;
        }
    }


    child_pid = fork();
    if(child_pid == 0)
    {
        int file;
        if(redirect_stdout == true)
        {
            file = open(argument[index + 1], O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666);
            dup2(file, 1);
            edit_arguments(argument, index);
            execvp(argument[0], argument);
            return(-1);
        }
        else if(redirect_stderr == true)
        {
            file = open(argument[index + 1], O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666);
            dup2(file, 2);
            edit_arguments(argument, index);
            execvp(argument[0], argument);
            return(-1);
        }

        execvp(argument[0], argument);
        return(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        wait(&child_status);
    }

    return(child_status);
}
```

comp20200Shell_header.h

```
/*
 * Name: ****
 * Student Number: ****
 * Email: ****
 *
 * This is my header file, It includes all common used headerfiles on the top.
 * Any specific header file that is only used once will be included with the .c file that needs it.
 *
 */

/* included headerfiles begin */
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
/* included headerfiles end */

/* defenitions begin */
#define PROMPT "# "
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#define BLUE_TEXT "\x1B[34m"
#define MAGENTA_TEXT "\x1B[35m"
#define GREEN_TEXT "\x1B[32m"
#define RESET_COLOUR "\x1B[0m"
/* defenitions end */

/* Function prototypes begin */
void remove_trailing_newline(char *input);
void sigintHandler(int sig_num);
int process_input(char** input);
char* return_time(void);
void error(const char *fmt, ...);
int change_directory(char* path);
char* return_current_directory(void);
void process_errors(int return_value);
void edit_arguments(char** argument, int index);
/* Function prototypes end */
```

I have omitted the rest of the source code as I don't think the problem is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your child, after the call to `execvp` you need to call `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` instead of `return -1;`. Otherwise your child will continue running, and will interpret the next command (that is why you need to exit `N` times where `N` is the number of inexistant commands you tried to invoke).

After the change, your parent process will see that the child terminated with a non-zero return code and should interpret the error code. There is no real way to distinguish between a failure from the `execvp` (due to a non-existent command) or from the invoked process. I would recommend printing the error from `execvp` if there is one in the child before the `exit`.

Note that if `execvp` succeed, it will never return, so the code following a call to `execvp` can only be executed if the command failed.

So, my recommendation is doing this:

```
if(child_pid == 0)
{
    int file;
    if(redirect_stdout == true)
    {
        file = open(argument[index + 1], O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666);
        dup2(file, 1);
        edit_arguments(argument, index);
        execvp(argument[0], argument);
        perror("execvp");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if(redirect_stderr == true)
    {
        file = open(argument[index + 1], O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666);
        dup2(file, 2);
        edit_arguments(argument, index);
        execvp(argument[0], argument);
        perror("execvp");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    execvp(argument[0], argument);
    perror("execvp");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
else
{
    wait(&child_status);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing `exit(1);` or equivalent instead of `return(-1);`.  You might want to use `_exit(1);`, or `_exit(255);` (or `_exit(-1);`, but it is equivalent to `_exit(255);`).  You might well want to print an error message to standard error before you exit.

When you don't exit, you end up with two, then three, then N shells all trying to read input from the terminal.  You have to make each one quit separately by indicating EOF with <kbd>Control-D</kbd>.  If you tried typing commands, then it would become a lottery which shell gets each character, and that leads to chaos (and grave danger; you may have thought you typed `grep fungible form.file | tr -d 'fr' > /tmp/x33` but if one of the shells got `rm -fr /`, you've got trouble!).

Comment: The child and father won't end up fighting in his implementation since he does not support background jobs (ie. the father does ` wait(&child_status);` just after forking).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of return -1, you can use exit(1) or exit (-1) to exit from that portion if it fails to execute due to some error.